# nmake.exe keeps complaining about flags I'm not giving it. (U1065)

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

When I run `nmake.exe` from `make` I get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.42
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1065: invalid option '-'
```

But I'm not passing in '-' as an option anyplace.

If I run the same command from outside of make it works correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the environment variables `MAKE` and `MAKEFLAGS` are set by `make`.  These are confusing `nmake.exe`.

To fix this, just prefix your call to `nmake.exe` with `env -u MAKE -u MAKEFLAGS`

Example:

```
 some-make-target:
      env -u MAKE -u MAKEFLAGS nmake.exe /a /l
```

Comment: What is this `env` command? It doesn't seem to be a standard cmd command. Are you using another shell for Make on Windows?

Comment: It isn't a windows tool.  It's a unix tool that I was using. I'm not sure what the equivalent Windows command would be. `env -u MAKE -u MAKEFLAGS` is unsetting `MAKE` and `MAKEFLAGS` environment variables for that one command only.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are on a windows prompt command, and you have a rule like that:

```
 target:
   cd ... && nmake.exe ...
```

by

```
 target:
   cd ... && set MAKEFLAGS= && nmake.exe ...
```

> `set FOO`: display the value of FOO if exist, (like `echo %FOO%`)
>
> `set FOO=`: unset FOO, (i.e. later call to `set FOO` will display
>   `Environment variable FOO not defined`)

note: there is no `unset` command

Answer (score 0):

if you use windows, simply go to Enviroment Variables in advance system setting and delete system variables "MAKEFLAGS". It should not confuse Nmake anymore.

Answer (score 0):

just use , it will set MAKEFLAGS Empty
`set MAKEFLAGS=`